# Can I use vstack to sum values between a range of date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to display the sum of item ordered between a range of date for each date of the calendar year using vstack formula.

So far I have managed to come up with something that is working but might require one or two tweaks with this formula:

```
=VSTACK("PO",MAP(H2:H430,LAMBDA(ROW,SUM(BYCOL(A2:E78,LAMBDA(col,SUMIFS(C2:C78,D2:D78,"PO",col,ROW)))))))
```

See outcome of the formula in cell G1

[image]

The only issue is that it is showing the value only for the specific starting or ending date, and not the dates in between which I would like to have as well.
Hope it makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What would be the expected output for the dates between?

Comment: Would you want to divide the numbers by the start/end range (average per day) or just show totals if it meets the condition? Wouldn't it in the latter case appear as if much more is sold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a condition for the dates as well.
Btw no need for `MAP` and `BYROW`.
You can use `SUMIFS` and for the dates `Table1[start date],"<=" &dates,Table1[end date],">="&dates`

```vb
=LET(dates, MIN(Table1[start date]) + SEQUENCE(MAX(Table1[end date],Table1[start date]) - MIN(Table1[start date],Table1[end date]),,0),
    sumTotal,SUMIFS(Table1[[total number]],`,Table1[end date],">="&dates,Table1[cat],"PO"),
    HSTACK(sumTotal,dates))
```

I built the dates column based on min and max date of the table.

[image]